# How can I use 'Regex' to extract a file name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to extract the file name `13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-06-28.zip` from the following text -

> 1:30","/icons/def13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-06-28.zip","13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-06-28.zip",0,"184296","Jun 28

The regular expression code I am using is:

```
var fileNames = from Match m in Regex.Matches(pageSource, @"[0-9]+_+[A-Za-z]+_+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+.+(acc|zip|app|xml|def|enr|exm|fpr|pnd|trm)")
                select m.Value;
```

Which should work fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Stupid question, but you have what appears to be CSV data there. Can you not use a CSV library instead?

Comment: @RB means that HIS question may be stupid, not that akhil's question is stupid.  Its a common, self-deprecating phrase in english.

Comment: @will I understand the fact,  but I think no question is ever stupid. May be its not properly organized but that doesn't call it a stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to escape the . in the middle of the regex because . matches for any character.

```
@"[0-9]+_+[A-Za-z]+_+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+\.+(acc|zip|app|xml|def|enr|exm|fpr|pnd|trm)"
```

Comment: Yes, but in order to match exactly the character . you have to use \. in your regex. You have to escape the dot to match it exactly, otherwise the regex assumes you mean that absolutely any character will do at the point you have the dot. http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regular expression:

```
[0-9]+_+[A-Za-z]+_+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+.+(acc|zip|app|xml|def|enr|exm|fpr|pnd|trm)(?=",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following regex:

```
\d{5}_\w*_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.(acc|zip|app|xml|def|enr|exm|fpr|pnd|trm)
```

This will match anything that:

1. Starts with five digits
2. Then an underscore
3. Then any number of letters or digits
4. Then an underscore
5. Then the date part: four digits, dash, two digits, dash, and then two final digits.
6. Then a period
7. And finally the extension.

PowerShell example:

```
$text = '1:30","/icons/def13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-06-28.zip","13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-06-28.zip",0,"184296","Jun 28'

$regex = '\d{5}_\w*_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.(acc|zip|app|xml|def|enr|exm|fpr|pnd|trm)'

$text -match $regex

$matches[0]
```

Comment: You can use that regex in your C# code. I just posted the PowerShell to prove it works ;-)